# Bulk update mysql table and calculate value from datagridview. VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I want to do bulk update my database table using value from datagridview, but also I need to sum the datagridview and mysql table value fisrt.
how do I do that?

here is my current code of my update button

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjvQO.png)

```
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvStok.Rows
            If (Not row.IsNewRow) Then
                Dim ID As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells("ID").Value
                Dim Stok As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells("Stok").Value

                conn = New MySqlConnection('myconnstring)
                conn.Open()

                cmd = New MySqlCommand("Select * from tbStok where ID='" & ID & "'", conn)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dr.Read()
                If dr.HasRows Then
                    Dim StokInventory, IncomingStok As Integer
                    StokInventory = dr.Item("Stok")
                    TotalStok = StokInventory + IncomingStok

                    Dim updateStok As String = "update tbStok set Stok ='" & TotalStok & "' where ID = '" & ID & "'"
                    cmd = New MySqlCommand(updateStok, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
                conn.Close()
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Where do we start.  Some of this might sound a little brutal so sorry up front, really isn't an easy way to say this.  1) On Error Resume Next - We are no longer in the 1990's there are now much better robust error handling methods.  And simply skipping to the next line shouldn't been ok back then either.

Comment: 2) Parametrise your query, the security stuff a side it just makes your project more robust

Comment: Your checking dr.HasRows, a good check, however you're doing dr.Read in the line above.    Not to mention you're only looking a the first row of your query results.  Is that Query supposed to be a Select Sum(Stok) From... maybe, and if so, read up on how to use ExecuteScaler()

Comment: On the question itself, could you perhaps update it (Not try and explain it in a comment) with a concise explanation of what exactly the problem is because as it stands It's very hard to follow, the image you've attached doesn't explain how you get from your DVG to the data stored in your DB.

Comment: I'm new to programming language. I'm just learning from the internet and then I've got this kind of problem while learning. I dont know who can guide me through this problem, so I asked here. perhaps you can give me the example of your code. thank you.

Comment: Wel... as per my last comment it's not even very clear (to me at least) what you're even attempting to do, and really there are a ton of topics you should read up on.  I would suggest reading over the offical docs before turning to any out dated youtube videos though.

Comment: Exception Handling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement.   ExecuteScaler https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0  Query Parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 MySql Group By Clause https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: I'm trying to update myql table using data that shown in my datagridview. because the data from datagridview is more than one so I need to use loop function to update every single row of my database table, but unfortunately I cant compile my code after applying the loop funtion. I've updated my code above, I'm away from my computer right now, as I remember it should look like that. I hope you can help me. thanks

Comment: Sorry if this is all sounding unhelpful but as you’ve mentioned you’ve trying to learn.  You might also want to read up on data adapters and data binding.  Sorry should of seen that at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution

```
Private Sub UpdateBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateBTN.Click
    Dim ID As String
    Dim StartingStok, IncomingStok, TotalStok As Integer

    For Each DGVR As DataGridViewRow In dgvStok.Rows
        ID = (DGVR.Cells("ID").Value)
        IncomingStok= (DGVR.Cells("Stok").Value)

        #open mysql connection string

        cmd = New MySqlCommand("Select * from tbStok where ID='" & ID & "'", conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then
            StartingStok = dr.Item("Stok")
        End If
        conn.Close()

        TotalStok = StartingStok + IncomingStok

        #open mysql connection string

        Dim UpdateTable As String = "update tbStok set Stok ='" & TotalStok & "' where ID = '" & ID & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(UpdateTable, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()
    Next
End Sub
```

This code will looping through datagridview and sum value from datagridview and mysql table for each ID(primary key) and then it will update the table with new value which is from summarizing datagridview table and mysql table for each ID